# Excel spreadsheet keeps getting overwritten with old data

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I was very fortunate to find snipets of code here and there and was able to build a macro that creates a letter.  The sender's information is taken from an Excel spreadsheet I populated with attorney names, address, phone number, etc.  The macro runs OK. The problem is, the spreadsheet keeps getting overwritten and records I've added last week are no longer there today. Records I deleted last week or even yesterday are there again there today. I wonder if the way I'm opening the spreadsheet (the connection) is contributing to this behavior or if it's on how the spreadsheet gets updated. To update it, I copy it from the server to my desktop, remove the read-only property, edit it, save changes and close it, then make it read-only again, and then copy it back to the server, overwriting the old one. There is a possibility someone is in the middle of running the macro while I'm editing the spreadsheet.  Here's the relevant code:

```
    Option Explicit

Public slkCompanyInfo As String
'This public variable is used in the Letter() macro. Do not delete this statement

Public Sub Letter()

Dim mySQLquery As String
Dim myKey As String
Dim mySource As String
Dim slkAddresseeName, slkRegarding, slkFileNum, slkSalutation As String
Dim slkTemplate As String
Dim myConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim myRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim slkTempDoc As String
Dim imgFullPath As String
imgFullPath = "\\server1\SignatureImages\"

' Prompt user for Login ID. Make sure it's all lowercase
myKey = LCase(InputBox("Enter Attorney or Paralegal User ID (e.g., jtorres or b324):"))

' Make DB connection
    mySQLquery = "SELECT * FROM [all_users$] WHERE LoginID = '" & myKey & "'"
    
    mySource = "\\server1\LetterMemoDB.xlsx"
    Set myConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set myRs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    With myConn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mySource & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
    End With
    myConn.Open
    myRs.Open mySQLquery, myConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
' End of DB connections

'Main block of code to build letter goes here.

    ' Place cursor at beginning of letter body
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Body"

    ' Cleanup
    myConn.Close
    Documents(slkTempDoc).Activate
    Unload frmLtrAddress
    
    Else: MsgBox "The Login ID you entered does not have an associated letter template. Please run the macro again and enter a valid Login ID.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid value entered or left blank"
    End If
Else: MsgBox "Please run the macro again and enter a valid Login ID at the prompt", vbOKOnly, "Invalid value entered or left blank"
End If
End Sub
```

I know I should list what I've tried already to fix the problem, but I can't imagine what to do. Any help you can provide will be appreciated.  I searched before posting, but didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: I should add, I'm using Word and Excel 2016.

Comment: There's not much we can do to guess why content in LetterMemoDB.xlsx might be different from what you expect: nothing in your posted code should be updating that file.  Seems like you either have an weird versioning problem, or someone else is editing the file without your knowledge.  Are the "missing" records really gone, or just not retrieved by the SQL query?

Comment: If the record exists in the spreadsheet, the SQL query always works. The problem is, I can put the record there and it’s gone tomorrow. My theory is, a user runs the macro. While the macro is running, I update the spreadsheet. It’s read only so I have to copy it down to my desktop, change permission, edit, save, change back permission to read only and put back on the server, replacing the old one, all this while the user is running the macro. When they’re done, the connection closes and the spreadsheet is overwritten with a temp copy from their hard drive. Is this possible? I will test this.

Comment: If the file is read-only then I'm pretty sure Excel can't replace it with a copy.  One way to be sure is to set the folder permissions where the file is located so that only you have write access and everyone else is read-only.

Comment: Something just came to mind. Several users have reported runtime error: "External table is not in the expected format."  Do you think this error may causing this or a related problem that leads to records being deleted from the spreadsheet?  but again, it's read-only...  UGH!

Comment: @TimWilliams, I will consider your suggestion.  There are other files in that folder.  Will see if all can have the same permissions.  Thanks!